# In Blazor, is it bad to alter fields or properties of a Parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, blazor

I'm making a class scheduling / homework assignment page.  I have several classes on the page, each with several periods.  To each period, which is displayed by providing a reference to "SingleClassPeriod" component, I can add books from a list.  My question: given that I'm not altering the **reference** that I'm providing as a parameter to each "SingleClasssPeriod" object, is it okay to edit the **contents** of the instance, like populating lists of books, people and so on?

To avoid concurrency / async latency problems, I use an event to notify the parent that I'm done editing (i.e. that it can now safely save the page info through the data layer).

**SingleClass.razor**

```
@foreach (var period in Class.Periods)
{
    <SingleClassPeriod Period=period />
}
```

**SingleClassPeriod**

```
<button @onclick="()=> Period.Books.Add(new Book())" />
<button @onclick="()=> OnFinishedEditing.InvokeAsync()" />

@code {
[Parameter]
    public ClassPeriod Period { get; set; }

[Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnFinishedEditing {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I think u will have a problem if u have save/cancel option and it does cancel and the edited data remains. I think u should always send a copy of the "period" and update it back in the main list when it does save.

Comment: That's a good point, tbh.  Right now, I'm okay with that persistent behavior, but it's possible that a year form now, I'm going to wonder where / how the data is getting changed.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with changing the state of your parameter per se. It's up to your algorithm and expectation to decide whether a change should happen and if so, when. If you are worried about several sources trying to read/write the same recource at once, then you could implement a semaphor-like pattern and a queue of actions to be done on the resource.

So, if your resource is being edited, then all subsequent actions would wait in the queue until the edit completed. And, if your resource is being read, then all writes would wait in the queue until all reads are complete (you can allow multiple entities to read the same resource at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is black and white. But, the general rule is yes, it is bad, as explained here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0.

Why?  Most people don't understand what they are doing so will soon shoot themselves in the foot!  Why doesn't my component work?  Why do I need to keep calling `StateHasChanged`?

Before you consider breaking the rule, you need to understand that the parameter you define in the parent (or cascade) is only loosely coupled with the property in the component.  The Renderer tracks the values of the fields/properties assigned in the parent and passes either copies or references to the component through a `ParameterView` object.

It's only when the component calls `parameters.SetParameterProperties(this)` that the values are applied to the component properties. Note that `SetParameterProperties` uses reflection to do the assigning so it's  rather an expensive operation!

Consider this alternative approach:

```cs
<h3>MyComponent</h3>

@code {
    private bool _initialized;
    
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]public string? Value { get; set; }

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        if (!_initialized && parameters.TryGetValue<string?>("Value", out string? value))
            this.Value = value;

        // do whatever you want if it a value isn't provided
        
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    //...
}
```

It doesn't use the parameter setter.  Instead it sets `Value` manually on the first call to  `SetParametersAsync` and then ignores any sets thereafter.

The problem with your method is what happens when you forget what what you did, or someone else needs to maintain the code at some point in the future?

Comment: Benny, I've kept this generic as you're question is generic.

Comment: Hi, Shaun.  I've asked (and you've answered) similar questions before, but I think my qustion this time is subtly different.  The Parameter I'm providing this time is a reference type, and that reference isn't actually being altered by the code.  In this case, I'm passing a "ClassPeriod" object, which has `List<IdentityUser> Teachers`, `List<Book> Books` and so on.  I'm adding or removing teachers or books.  I didn't show it in the OP, but the purpose of the EventCallback is to let the parent know that I'm done with the child and it can now call StateHasChanged.

Comment: Benny, I agree.  But the principle applies.  If you only want to take the value/reference on the first set then code it that way.  I'm a firm believer in writing code so it ONLY does what you intent it to do.  And it saves CPU cycles on not doing the reflection stuff.